# when resize window, how to make image bigger without any stretching horizontally & vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Whenever I resize the window, some spaces are not filled with image I coded to insert. Actually, I tried to handle this many times with several approaches.

Here are some parts of my code.
(I use jquery, jquery-ui, and bootstrap)

**HTML**

```
<div id="carouselSection" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- Indicators are skipped -->

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active">
        <div class="carouselImage">
            <div id="black">
                <img src="img/carousel_img_opt/slide_001.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.carouselSection {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#black {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* for darkening */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image: url('bg_dim.png'); /* for checkered */
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index:10;
}

.carousel-inner .carouselImage img {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top:0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

I made this function for adjusting carousel part (of course including images) to the window's size.

```
function resizeCarousel(){
    $('#carouselSection').css('height', $(window).height());
    $('.carouselImage, #black').css('height', $(window).height());
    // $('.carouselImage img').css({'top': 'auto', 'left': 'auto', 'min-width': '100%'});
}
```

The comment part is problem.

If I change the `.carouselImage img`'s css "min-width' make '100%', and then making window longer (vertically), just `#black` part is showing without image.

Or I change that img's "min-height" make "100%", and then making window widely (horizontally), `#black` part is showing without image.

So, I made both height & width 100% when resizing, then image go stretching. (But I don't want that stretching because it's ugly ㅠㅠ)

Does anybody know how to handle this problem?
Actually, I want this kind of effect (main images within carousel slide) in https://www.linefriends.com/.

I tried to copy the html(including js file), css code from that website. But I didn't get any idea from it.

(Actually, it seems like there's a little bit of zooming in/out effect on linefriends' website. But I could not find that effect on the code. I think the effect that I want might not the problem of height or width. But, if you catch how to build linefriends' effect, please let me know.)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3):

If you give your slide container a static height (you can use `height: calc(100%);`, you can use `background-image` and `background-size: cover;` to display an image which does NOT stretch when resized. See code below:

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="carouselImage" style="background-image: url('img/carousel_img_opt/slide_001.png');>
        <div id="black">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! and what I have to do is just editing some code for that xD Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, I honestly think `background-size: cover;` is a gift from the CSS gods.